# fb.login() on mobile browser does not open native facebook app

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, facebook-login

I know this has been asked before but there are no good answers. Here is the problem:

1. My mobile friendly site on mobile safari or mobile chrome calls
   Fb.Login() method for Facebook authentication
2. Instead of opening the native FB app, it opens a new browser window
   where the user is almost never logged in.
3. The problem with this is that I see 95% of the people drop off as
   they either don't remember their password or don't want to sign in
   on safari since they already have Facebook app where they are signed
   in.
4. On top of that, these days people are really wary about typing their
   passwords if it is initiated by another app, so that is the cause of
   95% people dropping off from that point.

Questions (hopefully facbeook team sees this):

1. Can facebook app not set a cookie so that when safari is use to go to facebook.com, it knows who the logged in user is and just signs them in?
2. Can I not invoke facebook native app for login authentication

This is a horrible horrible user experience which is evident by all
these people dropping off from the sign in page (Please don't ask
how I came up with 95%. I used google analytics to track this behavior)

Hopefully someone can give a good answer and/or facebook team can do something about this.